# How to search on all my likes in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Last year one of my friends shared an article. I liked it. Now there are tons of updates in between. How do I find that article again?

Comment: I haven't got an answer yet it is an intriguing question; if I ever find out I'll let you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to go to your own [All Activity](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity) page and select `Likes` from the dropdown that says "All". This will show you the list of things (statuses, pages, photos, etc) that you have liked broken down by month.

Comment: this is nice, but is there a link to go to this page or should i write the url each time to go to it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.likejournal.com

Comment: Unfortunately, Likejournal only uses Facebook Graph's `Like` API call. Which will only display pages that you've liked, not individual status messages.  You can see the same thing here: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token= but you'll need to get an access token which happens to be autofilled (if you're logged in) on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Also on that page you can look for `Likes` and click that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using FQL to query for posts shared by your friend that you have liked

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Can you elaborate as to how they would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since May [Bing is supposed to](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/search/archive/2011/05/16/news-announcement-may-17.aspx)

> make it easier to see what your Facebook friends “like” ...

provided that you are logged in to your facebook account. However, the search results depend on many factors so your likes are not guaranteed to appear at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Click your name on the header, next to search field.
Click "Activity log" on your cover photo.
Click "Likes" in the left sidebar.
Voila!